# AngularJS syntax error while using ng-style for background gradient

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

AngularJS syntax error while using ng-style for background gradient & not working in IE 11 if I use only style tag. Need help

```
<div class="test-data" ng-style="{{statusStyle}}"></div>

var empty = 100 - status.test;

$scope.statusStyle = {'background': 'linear-gradient(#f2f2f2 ' + empty + '%, ' + color + ' ' + empty + '%)'};


Error: [$parse:lexerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.16/$parse/lexerr?p0=Unexpected%20nextharacter%20&p1=s%2028-28%20%5B%23%5D&p2=background%3A%20linear-gradient(%cbcbcb%2026%25%2C%20%2378bc00%2026%25)%3B
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost:52000/Scripts/ext-lib.js?v-635938893578389223:20:417
    at kc.throwError (http://localhost:52000/Scripts/ext-lib.js?v-635938893578389223:201:190)
    at kc.lex (http://localhost:52000/Scripts/ext-lib.js?v-635938893578389223:200:49)
    at lb.parse (http://localhost:52000/Scripts/ext-lib.js?v-635938893578389223:204:178)
    at http://localhost:52000/Scripts/ext-lib.js?v-635938893578389223:124:366
    at m.$watch (http://localhost:52000/Scripts/ext-lib.js?v-635938893578389223:134:310)
    at http://localhost:52000/Scripts/ext-lib.js?v-635938893578389223:250:437
    at Xc (http://localhost:52000/Scripts/ext-lib.js?v-635938893578389223:84:279)
    at M (http://localhost:52000/Scripts/ext-lib.js?v-635938893578389223:73:323)
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the variable "empty"?

Comment: @Jeff Diederiks I have edit the code

Comment: In the div, you are setting `style` not `ng-style` ?

Comment: @Chris I had earlier style only. It works in modern browsers but not in IE11 and fix for that is ng-style as suggested on stack overflow. It was a bug in AngularJS by it self & ng-style

Comment: Problem solved my grunt file was not compiling properly bloody Visual studio. There is no syntax error but the top the code I have put is a solution for IE11 fix use ng-style instead of style. Thanks for you help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code change

```
<div class="test-data" style="background: {{statusStyle}}"></div>

var empty = 100 - status.test;

$scope.statusStyle = 'linear-gradient(#f2f2f2, ' + color + ' ' + empty + '%)';
```

This change makes the {{statusSyle}} angular expression evaluate as a JavaScript string and not a JavaScript object set with { field : "value", ...}. The AngularJS syntax error is likely resulting from trying to write the $scope.styleStatus object to your expression.

The other change is the inclusion of only one %  in the color-stops for the linear gradient. Use the % only in the second color-stop.

CSS3 Linear Gradients have been supported in most browsers for some time.

General Syntax:
*background: linear-gradient(direction, color-stop1, color-stop2, ...);*

With both color stops set to the same % you will not get a linear gradient but a color break at the % value entered with the first color and generally the browser ignores the % on the second color.

Use this example code below in your browser to test some linear gradients.

*HTML Code*

```
<body>
<div id="grad"></div>

To create a linear gradient you must define at least two color stops. Color stops are the colors you want to render smooth transitions among. You can also set a starting point and a direction (or an angle) along with the gradient effect.  

<br>  
Syntax:<br>  

background: linear-gradient(direction, color-stop1, color-stop2, ...);
</body>
```

Styling

```
#grad {
  width: 100%;
  height: 620px;
  background: red; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, yellow 90%); 
     /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(red, yellow 90%); 
     /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(red, yellow 90%); 
     / For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(red, yellow 90%); 
     /* Standard syntax */
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is another way but this will not work in IE 11. The orignal code I have will work in IE as well. Difference is "style" and "ng-style"